# memory and Interface Builder objects

Tags: objective-c, iboutlet

i'm a little confused about memory managment with IB objects, here what i've done:

- i've a navigation controller, i push other view with

  ...[[[viewController alloc]init]autorelease]...
- I connect EACH element of Interface Builder to a IBOutlet so defined:

  @property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet *object

  and in .m file :   `@synthesize object = _object`
- Then in viewDidUnload: self.object = nil;
- Finally in `dealloc` method:  `[_object release];`

Is this a right way to manage Interface Builder object's memory?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did everything correct.

Just one thing - you don't have to make outlets for all your UI elements, you can create them only for those you need to access in code.